# Typeclass or add a method via implicit?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, implicit

I'm designing sort of `Service`s and faced with a design issue. Here is what I currently have:

```
trait Service {
  def isFailed(): Boolean
  def start(): Unit
  def stop(): Unit
}
```

And in order to group `Service`s related to each other in a group (in order to restart/recover the group, not other services) I created the following package object:

```
package object app {
  type FaultTolerantServiceGroup = Seq[Service]
  object FaultTolerantServiceGroup{
    def apply(svcs: Service*): FaultTolerantServiceGroup = Seq(svcs: _*)
  }

  class FaultTolerantServiceGroupOps(val F: FaultTolerantServiceGroup){
    def hasFailed: Boolean = F.forall(_.failed())
  }

  trait FaultTolerantServiceGroupSyntax{
    implicit def serviceGroup2Ops(F: FaultTolerantServiceGroup) = new FaultTolerantServiceGroupOps(F)
  }
}
```

So I added the method `hasFailed` to `FaultTolerantServiceGroup`. But I'm not sure about this decision.

Would it be better to define a typeclass, say

```
trait Watchable[T]{
     def hasFailed(t: T): Boolean
}
```

And implicitly provide an instance of `Watchable[FaultTolerantServiceGroup]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion implicit functions become much harder to read afterwards.  Even when reading my old code it can sometimes be confusing when objects have methods that appear out of the blue.

I have yet to see an instance where implicits are easier to reason about than declarative functions:

```
val failedGroup : FaultTolerantServiceGroup => Boolean = _.forall(_.failed())
```

The resulting code doesn't seem any better, or worse, than implicits but at least it's obvious where functionality is coming from:

```
val group : FaultTolerantServiceGroup = ???

//no implicit
val failed = failedGroup(group)

//with implicits : how does a Seq have a hasFailed method?
val failed = group.hasFailed
```

Explicit functions also make `Iterable` functions easier to read:

```
val groups : Iterable[FaultTolerantServiceGroup] = ???

val failedGroups = groups filter failedGroup
```